# Proving $e^{A}S=Se^{B} for AS=SB$, why do we have $y(x)=e^{Ax}Sz_0$ as a solution?

Tags: matrices, ordinary-differential-equations

I am working on this problem:
[Prove $e^AS = S e^B$ for $AS=SB$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2148746/prove-eas-s-eb-for-as-sb/2149523)

I don't understand why in [this answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/2149523/811720) we have that $y(x) = e^{Ax}Sz_0$ is a solution to the system $y'=Ay$.

I can only see that $y(x) = e^{Ax}$ is a fundamental matrix solution to the system but that doesn't seem to help for the proof.

Could someone shed some light on why this is the case?

Comment: It's a solution because of the initial condition given ie $y(0)=Sz_0$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The general solution for  a problem $y'=Ay$ will be $y(x)=e^{Ax}y(0)$, remember your constants of integration.  Using the initial condition $y(0)=Sz_0$ give you the solution.

Remember, these linear systems on $\mathbb{R}^n$ evolve by applying the given matrix to the initial position $y(0)$ which gives the direction the system will evolve.  This defines a curve in $\mathbb{R}^n$ passing through the point $y(0)$ who's tangent vector at each point is obtained by applying the matrix $A$ to the position vector on the curve.

Comment: If we have an initial condition $y(0)=y_0$ in general, afaik the constants would be determined by solving the system $e^{Ax}c=y_0$ where c is the vector of constant that we are looking for. Then the solution to the IVP is $y(x)=e^{Ax}c$. So how can that vector c be the same as $y(0)=y_0$?

Comment: $e^{A(0)}=I$ where $I$ is the identity matrix